# Colors not respected in some cases: dark mode in react native

Tags: android, react-native

i'm developing an app in react native, using expo, and testing it on my device (xiaomi red mi note 9).

in the main page i have an icon, and i give it a color that depends on the dark or light mode of the device, and this one works.

when i click this icon, it opens a modal, here i have:
a radio button coming from "react native paper"
and a Pressable coming from "react-native"
with colors set the same as the icon on the main page.

When i switch the device in dark mode, theese two components in the modal have darkers colors **and i cant set the same color as the icon in the main page, not even modyfing it**..

Why? and how to match the color of the icon?

you can see the screenshot.
[image]

I'd like to have all three colors like the + icon in the upper right.

Here is the code from expo snackbar, https://snack.expo.dev/@giuse90/snackbar?platform=android
but here i can't set the dark mode so i can't show you the problem from there (on expo snackbar usecolorscheme allways return "light", so colors dont change) The screen is taken directly on my phone.